# C - catching wrong parameter errors

Tags: c, visual-studio, parameters

I'm working with a large C-only project, and I keep getting bitten by the following problem:

Lets say I have a function

```
void MyFunction(int parameter)
{
    printf("parameter: %d\n", parameter);
}
```

Which normally gets called

```
int aVariable = 5;
MyFunction(aVariable);
```

However, apparently due to the C standard specifications, this does not cause a compilation error:

```
int aVariable = 5;
MyFunction(&aVariable); // No error signaled, but causes all sorts of mayhem
```

How can I catch this kind of error, specifically in Visual Studio? Is there any setting I can turn on to make it stricter? 
Any strategy you might recommend (besides "don't make typos")?

Edit:
I might add that due to the (crappy) nature of the project, the sample code already generates tons of warnings; I am not sure I can remove all of them in the time I have. Generating more warnings might not be the best option -- however being able to discern about these specific warnings (as one answer suggests) might be the solution to this particular problem.

Comment: Does the compiler see a prototype of MyFunction? (before it gets to the line `MyFunction(&variable);`)

Comment: Do you have function prototypes in header files?

Comment: @aschepler yes, I have this problem even with functions with prototypes specified in header files

Comment: Set the warning level to `-W4`.

Comment: Warnings, warnings. I get 2 off the line `MyFunction(&aVariable);`

Comment: @user3386109 OK, I will try that tomorrow and update. However, I am afraid that if it only turns on more warnings they will get lost among the tons that are already generated today (we're using a really horrendous library; the project is a nightmare. Unfortunately nothing that can be done about the library)

Comment: Tons of warnings? Deal with them, one by one. Perhaps it's not the libray's fault but the way you are using it.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for the idea. I'm not sure it's possible due to the library we're using (not my choice).

Comment: Did you turn them off? `/W1` should be enough in this case. Visual Studio projects default to `/W3`.

Comment: If it's a library then it's precompiled: it doesn't give warnings. The way you call it does.

Comment: @Alejandro Yup, I know that feeling. One project I was hired to fix had 240 warnings when I first compiled it. About 30 of those were actual bugs. So you've got three choices: a) find and fix all the warnings, b) spend the rest of your life debugging crappy code, or c) run away!!! and get a another job :)

Comment: Turning off warnings, sticking your head in the sand, and blaming the library isn't going to get you far. Better to understand the library you have to use in the first place. Your example of passing `int*` to `int` parameter proves my point.

Comment: @user3386109 So it seems. I'll check the feasiblity of going through all the warnings. Additionally I will check with different warning levels. There might be some that leave the warnings I'm looking for and hide the others.
(I have actually considered option c too :P)

Comment: @WeatherVane the example is oversimplified, so don't take it as proof of anything. 
With tons of warnings, I mean easily 1000+ . Not my code. Sample project code, that is almost unreadable. I appreciate your attempt to help, however.

Comment: Oh.. some people might recommend a can of gas and a box of matches for this job.  I couldn't possibly comment myself.

Comment: If it is your your job to fix an inherited catastrophe, start at the first warning, and work your way through methodically. Or leave.

Comment: @WeatherVane OK. You've made your point. I get it. It might not be possible. Again, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: ... but it might be possible. Be upbeat to fuel you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function `MyFunction` is *declared with prototype* before the point of the call, then

```
MyFunction(&aVariable);
```

is a genuine full-blown *constraint violation* in C, i.e. it is what we usually call "an error". That's what the language specification says. In other words, your belief that this is somehow allowed "due to the C standard specifications" is incorrect: this is explicitly disallowed by C standard.

Any C compiler will issue at least a *warning* for such code, which you should also pay attention to. If your C compiler does not report this violation as an *error*, it can usually be changed through compiler setup.

In case of Visual Studio compiler, one approach is to watch the warning number issued in such cases and ask the compiler to convert such warnings into errors. This can be done through either `#pragma warning` or through project settings.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I have started addressing most warnings and have turned a few into errors, so that no matter what they cannot be ignored.
Thank you also for the explanation as it helps clarify why these errors went unnoticed in the first place (the prototypes were there and generating warnings when misused, only they got lost in way too many warnings!).

Answer (score 2):

Insert a function declaration of the form

```
 void MyFunction(int parameter);
```

before attempting to call it.   If you don't do that, when calling `MyFunction()` a C compiler is required to assume `MyFunction()` accepts a variable argument list (arbitrary number and types of arguments) and returns int.

Hence code will compile without error, even if the function is called with incorrect arguments or calling code attempts to use the return value (which should not be done with a `void` function).    The result, if the arguments supplied do not match what the actual function definition expects, is often in the realm of undefined behaviour.

Declaring the function before calling it is good practice, and allows the compiler to detect a problem, and issue errors or warnings as needed.  Without the declaration, some compilers do issue warnings, but not all compilers do.